# DeprecationWarning in mongoose connection despite setting it it to be true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am receiveing these deprecation warnings despite passing in the arguments as I believe I should be, and I am not sure why.  I have a mongoose connection config file setup, and it does not seem to work

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config   = require('config');
const db       = config.get('mongoURI');

mongoose.connect(db);

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });
        
        console.log("Mongoose database connected");
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        // Exit program with error
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

Is there something I am missing here?  Even with this file setup this way, I am still receiving these errors:

```
(node:9464) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Server initialized on port 5000
(node:9464) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Mongoose database connected
```

Thank you.

Comment: Link to documentation you are following?

Comment: I am using the documentation here, but maybe I am implementing it incorrectly: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling

```
mongoose.connect(db);
```

without providing any options. That call probably generates the warnings you see.